# Why javascript dont do else?

Tags: javascript, html, button, switch-statement

I am trying to make a switch button in html and javascript but is not working, the button change one time and then it stay pressed.

The html code:

```
<div class="button-div" unselectable="on">
        <img id="button" src="images/button/button.png" onclick="btnClick()">
</div>
```

The javascript code:

```
if (document.getElementById('button').src = "images/button/button.png"){
        document.getElementById('button').src = "images/button/buttonPressed.png";
    }else{
        document.getElementById('button').src = "images/button/button.png";
}
```

Comment: = vs == vs ===. In your case do `document.getElementById('button').src = document.getElementById('button').src.indexOf("pressed") === -1 ? "images/button/buttonPressed.png" : "images/button/button.png";`

Comment: Work the same, it switch one time and stay with that image.

Comment: Nope. It works https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/on9gwpa4/

Comment: Sorry I am insistent but I don't understand why with my images is not working. Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/o7pna2L8/

Comment: `button.src.indexOf("Pressed")` instead of `button.src.indexOf("pressed")` - case